# BroadCastReceiver calls Service

Tags: android

Hi I am using this code to call a Service from BroadCastReceiver but its not working.
here is the code:

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("luli");
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,AlarmReceiver.class);
      // myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        context.startService(myIntent);
    } 
}
```

then on my Service I have this code:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("HEY u bastard service print at least something");
    return null;
}
```

}

I have also declared in Manifest the service

What is wrong here that is not responding the Service??

Comment: I trie to call the BroadCastReceiver from another class Alarm and it prints that message luli, but i also wanna do something else in Service for example play some sound as long as I am making an AlarmClock app.

Comment: Show the manifest and the code binding your service.

Comment: this part is in my manifest file:  <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <service android:name=".AlarmService">
  </service>

Comment: Stop abusing your onBind function...:D

Answer (score 1):

You override [`onBind()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onBind%28android.content.Intent%29). Thats only called when someone creates a persistent connection to the service via binding (`Context.bindService()`). You should rather override [`onStartCommand()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: if i remove OnBind then it shows me an error the Service it says to implement that method

Comment: Yes, you have to implement onBind(). Just leave the method empty, it won't be called anyway and has no use in your case. Then add your log call (println in this case) into onStartCommand(). Every time you call startService() now, it will print a log statement.

Comment: Unable to start service intent {cmp=luli/.AlarmReceiver} not found, this is message i see on logCat. and I am wondering why it is saying AlarmReceiver since my Service name is AlarmService.

Comment: That's an entirely different problem with the receiver. Don't see any issues though, so not sure what causes this.